# LinearLayout without border color when pressed

Tags: android, border, android-linearlayout, background-color

I have a **ListView**. In each row I have a **LinearLayout** with items inside. The LinearLayout has a **layout_margin** of 10dp. I have placed it a selector background when pressed. But the problem is that at the border of the margin of 10dp an orange background color appears, while inside the LinearLayout black background appears correctly.

How I can remove that orange background in margin from appearing?

**selector**

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <gradient android:angle="90" android:startColor="@color/negro" android:endColor="@color/negro" />
    </shape>
</item>

    <item android:state_enabled="true">
    <shape>
        <gradient android:angle="90" android:startColor="@color/grisOscuro" android:endColor="@color/grisOscuro" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

**xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:id="@+id/fondoListviewRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

...

</LinearLayout>
```

**code**

holderName.fondo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_negro);

Comment: do you have an orange background somewhere behind the list?

Comment: no, it´s a orange background created when LinearLayout is pressed

Comment: and the orange color appears just at some portion of margin? or the complete 10dp is orange? it would be nice if you can put a screenshot or something

Comment: the complete 10dp margin are orange

Comment: you cannot change the color of margin as far as i know. (if that is what you want). you can try to put the LinearLayout inside another layout and set the background of that layout to say black or white.. so that the orange color does not apear. pls post a screenshot and little more code. i can conclude this much only for the given question

Comment: I have edited the XML code. When onclick, black Linearlayout is orange background and grey LinearLayout is black background. How I delete orange background?

Comment: remove the margin from outer layout and put it in inner layout and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppse there is a orange background behind your view.

> Padding

is the space inside the border, between the border and the actual view's content. Note that padding goes completely around the content: there is padding on the top, bottom, right and left sides (which can be independent).

> Margins

are the spaces outside the border, between the border and the other elements next to this view. Note that, like the padding, the margin goes completely around the content: there are margins on the top, bottom, right, and left sides.

Try using android:padding="10dp" insted. it should solve you problem.

EDIT:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#FF0000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#00FF00" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

the above code gives me

[image]

Comment: I want LinearLayout has margin top, bottom, left and right 10dp

Comment: if you want margin, the also its fine. but it will be transparent and whatever color there will be in background view will be reflected in margin. in your case it seems to have an orange background behind so the margin is orange.

Comment: There is not solution?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of the problem, I believe you should switch or alter the theme of your app, which is chosen in your app's manifest, under application » android:theme. Styles can be found under res » values. Or you should redefine styles related to elements of interest.

Before digging deep into this, switch theme to:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black"
```

or

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
```

or

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

... and see what happens. The latter shows no action bar.